# Linear mixed model right?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures

I was wondering if a linear mixed model is appropriate for my data.

It looks like this:

```
dat

id   group    cond1  cond2   outcome
1     trt      a       x       ...
1     trt      a       y
1     trt      b       x
1     trt      b       y
1     trt      a       x       ...
1     trt      a       y
1     trt      b       x
1     trt      b       y 
2     cntr     a       x 
2     cntr     a       y
2     cntr     b       x
2     cntr     b       y
...
```

So we have two groups (between-subjects-factor) and repeated measures (within-subjects-factor) out of two crossed factors: Each subject was assigned to one of two groups. Then, each subject was measured multiple times (but in one session) on a task which consisted of a combination of cond 1 and cond2.

I thought that a linear mixed model would be useful to answer my question whether the subjects differed in trt group more in a certain combination of cond 1 and cond 2.

I thought I would set my model up like this:

```
library(nlme)

baselinemodel<- (outcome ~ 1, random= ~ 1| participants/ cond1 / cond2, data= dat, method = "ML"=
```

then, build my model with `update()`
and my predictors would be cond1 and cond2.

Am I on the right way?

Comment: Are we seeing all the values for `cond1` and `cond2`? That is, each has just two possible values?

Comment: Yup, Cond 1 is a two level factor and Cond 2 is a two level factor. So it is a 2 x 2x 2- Design (with 5 obersvations for each combination of cond 1 and cond 2 for each subject, so 20 observations per subject)